# Problema con CrawlSpider en Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

Estoy intentando extraer información de la página elblogdelnarco.com usando como clase CrawlSpider pero no logro hacer que funcione, les muestro mi código:

```
from scrapy.item import Field, Item
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
import scrapy

class misitems(Item): 
    tipo = Field()
    capacidad = Field()

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "blog"
    allowed_domains = ["elblogdelnarco.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://elblogdelnarco.com/2019/06/21/la-vez-que-sicarios-del-cjng-de-el-mencho-presumieron-su-poder-en-calles-de-ciudad-de-mexico-video/"]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=("//a[@class='next page-numbers']/@href"))),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=("//h2[@class='title front-view-title']/a/@href")), callback='parse_item'),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = ItemLoader(misitems(), response)
        item.add_xpath("titulo", "//h1[@class='title single-title entry-title']/text()")
        item.add_xpath("contenido", "(//div[@class='thecontent']/p/b)[1]/text()")
        yield item.load_item()
```